# Can you use array elements when adding a new line to a CSV file?

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

I am writing a Perl script and using the [Class::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~djr/Class-CSV-1.02/CSV.pm) module. I have an array of numbers, 5 elements long

```
$values[0] - $values[4]
```

I am trying to add a new line to the CSV file and populate the new line with the values from the array. However I keep receiving this error when I try to run the script:

```
 Failed to create CSV line from line:
 10252205 
 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Class/CSV.pm line 257
    Class::CSV::Line::string('Class::CSV::Line=HASH(0x1f2d0f20)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Class/CSV.pm line 435
    Class::CSV::string('Class::CSV=HASH(0x1f2c1c00)') called at catchmailstats.pl line 116
```

Here is the code for the CSV construction:

```
# Create csv file from the current data
  my $csv = Class::CSV->new(
  fields  => [qw/Month NotSpam Probable Quarantine Spam Total/],
  );

# Creates the first row (Headers)
$csv->add_line({
  Month   => 'Month',
  NotSpam => 'NotSpam',
  Probable => 'Probable',
  Quarantine => 'Quarantine',
  Spam => 'Spam',
  Total => 'Total'
});

# Creates the second row (values)
$csv->add_line([$values[0], $values[1],$values[2],$values[3],$values[4], $total]);
```

I have also tried it using the other notation style:

```
# Creates the second row (values)
$csv->add_line({
  Month   => $values[0],
  NotSpam => $values[1],
  Probable => $values[2],
  Quarantine => $values[3],
  Spam => $values[4],
  Total => $total
});
```

Neither style has worked. Here is something I have noticed, though. The final variable, $total, is the sum of $values[1] through $values[4]. This variable will work just fine.

So my real question is: why won't references to elements in my array work, but a summation of elements from the same array, compile without a problem? And how can I get the add_line function to accept my array elements?

Comment: My mistake. $values[1]. I have made the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your values list, there's a `HASH REF` that needs to be dereferenced.

Use `Data::Dumper` in your code :

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @values;
```

And POST the output, we will see.

Comment: Here is the output from print Dumper @values:

`$VAR1 = '2012-05
';
$VAR2 = '
10252205
';
$VAR3 = '
62192
';
$VAR4 = '
55995
';
$VAR5 = '
3797710
';`

Comment: I think you are on to somehting sputnick. $total does not have single quotes around the value: $VAR1 = '2012-05 '; $VAR2 = ' 10252205 '; $VAR3 = ' 62192 '; $VAR4 = ' 55995 '; $VAR5 = ' 3797710 '; $VAR1 = 14168102;

The last $VAR1 is $total.

Comment: Can you do that on each values ? `print ref($_), "\n" for ($values[0], $values[1],$values[2],$values[3],$values[4], $total);`

Comment: It returned about 6 blank lines.

Comment: do you mean `print ref($value[0]);` for each one?

Comment: Ok, not some ref. Can you try without the `[ ]` in the last line for `$csv->add_line()` ?

Comment: Got this back when I compiled it:

`Need the arguments passed as either an ARRAY ref or a HASH ref!`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error simply because I had a new line character in one of the values in add_line.

Here's how to deal with a newline in the your values http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.18/CSV_XS.pm#Embedded_newlines